# Load a Select from Radio in Flask/Python using JavaScript / jQuery [Edited again to attend comments]

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm trying to **load a input select control when the user select a radio option** in the form.

First, the generated html script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App</title>    
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="/static/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">      
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <form action="/home" method=post>
    
            <!-- Radio Type -->
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="type-0" name="type" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="type-0">Incomes</label>
                    </label>            
                
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="type-1" name="type" type="radio" value="2"> <label for="type-1">Expenses</label>
                    </label>            
                

            <!-- categoria -->
            <div class="form-group   col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="category">Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                    <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Cat 2</option>
                    <option value="1">Cat 3</option>
                    <option value="1">Cat 4</option>
            </div>
             
           
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          ($("#type").is(":checked"))(function() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/select_type",
                  data: {info: $("#type").val()},
                  success: function(data) {
                      $("#category").html(data);
                  }
              });
          });

          
        });        
      </script>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

The fields are built with flask-wtf, and populated dinamically in the view *(no problem with that)*:

```
class FormRecord(Form):
    type = RadioField('Type')
    category = SelectField('Category')
```

The JS script would execute the view that populate my select control:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      ($("#type").is(":checked"))(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{{ url_for('select_type') }}",
              data: {info: $("#type").val()},
              success: function(data) {
                  $("#category").html(data);
              }
          });
      });


});
```

It seems the javascript is not working correctly, but what I am doing wrong ?

(I edited my doubt to be more clear)

This is my view select_type:

```
@app.route('/select_type', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def select_type():
    user_id = getattr(g, 'user', None).get_id()
    id_type = int(request.form['info'])
    cats = mngt.load_cats_tuples_by_type(user_id, id_type)
    data = ''
    for cat in cats:
        data += '<option value="{}">{}</option>'.format(str(subcat[0]),subcat[1]) 
    return data
```

This another view loads the form:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():

    # id do usuário logado
    user_id = getattr(g, 'user', None).get_id()    

    # formulário de registro
    form = forms.FormRecord()

    # carrega controle select dinamicamente
    form.subcategory.choices = mngt.load_subcats_tuples(user_id)
    form.category.choices = mngt.load_cats_tuples(user_id)

    # carrega controle radio dinamicamente
    form.type.choices = mngt.load_types_tuples()
    form.type.default = mngt.get_type_default()

    # processa o formulário, se o
    # form ainda não foi submetido (via PUT ou POST)
    # ao chamar process(), perde-se os valores default
    if not form.is_submitted():
        form.process()

    # o mesmo que form.is_submitted() and form.validate()    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ....
```

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working correctly ? Do you get error in Web Browser console or in Web Server ? Do you have routing `select_type` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to debug, the view was not executed when I check the radiobutton option. I put the complete example to be more clear. 'categoory' is the name of select.

Comment: If JavaScript is not working, don't give us the `flask` code. Paste the generated HTML and JavaScript and tag the question as [tag:jquery] [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 0):

**MY SOLUTION**

Finally, I found a solution that works fine to me (but I think that this is not the best and maybe a little ugly)

I missed a way to debug the interaction between javascript and my flask app. It take a log time to understand some issues, but finally worked.

1. Firstly, the Javascript / jQuery code. I was based on the following links: https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/ and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/jquery/:

> ```
>     <script type=text/javascript>
>             $(function() {
>               $("input[name=type]").change(function() {
>                     $.getJSON("{{ url_for('background_process') }}", {
>                       type: $('input[name="type"]:checked').val(),
>                     }, function(data) {
>                       $("#category").html(data.options);
>                     });
>                     return false;
>               });
>             });
>     </script>
> ```

2. Second, my html test form:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <h3>Welcome! Which is the best programming language of them all?</h3>
        <form>
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="1">Option 1<br>
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="2">Option 2<br>
                <select id="category"></select>                
                <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Send this</button></a>   
        </form>
        <p id=result></p>
{% endblock %}
```

3. Lastly, The flask view that will load the select control when a radio option be selected have these commands:

   - `id_type = request.args.get('type', 0, type=str)`
   - `options = '<option value="1">X1</option><option value="1">X2</option>'`
   - `return jsonify(options=options)`

So, this solution had three parts:

- *A little of Javascript*: The Javascript source. To triggler the view function when the user selects a radio option - that funtion will load the select control automatically;
- *The Html Form*: Ahtml form source (for the example), that has the controls: **radio** and **select**
- *The backend function* (I made it in flask view function: **def background_process()**